# PHP Calendar: Events seem to repeat themselves

Tags: php

I am busy coding a website that you can add an event to a calendar from a list of events stored in a database, and then the calendar will show the event for the amount of days the event is meant to go on.

So for example I have "Tennis Competition" that is 15 days long (specified in the database), then all I do is click on the day and choose the event, and it is meant to show the event for that day and the next 15 days.

If someone could maybe help me out with the next 15 days thing, as I've gotten stuck on how I will do that, if it will be when I add the event to the calendar just to add it 15 times, or add it once and let the calendar do the work.

Another problem I am having is that if I add an event for the 14th, and another for the 15th, both events will appear on the 15, and for the rest of the month.

Here is my code, I will be more specific on certain things if asked:

**event.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <title>Nkoka Courses: Admin Panel - Add Calendar Event</title>
        <a href="../style.css" rel= "stylesheet" type="text/css"></a>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Show/Add Courses:</h1>
<?php
$mysql = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
        if (!$mysql){
            die("Database Connection Failed" . mysql_error());
        }
        $select_db = mysql_select_db('nkoka');
        if (!$select_db){
            die("Database Selection Failed" . mysql_error());
        }

//add any new event
if ($_POST) {

    //create database-safe strings
    $m = $_POST['m'];
    $d = $_POST['d'];
    $y = $_POST['y'];
    $safe_event = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['event']);

    $startdate = $y."-".$m."-".$d;

    $insEvent_sql = "INSERT INTO calendar (event, startdate) VALUES('".$safe_event."', '".$startdate."')";
    $insEvent_res = mysql_query($insEvent_sql) or die(mysql_error($mysql));

} else {

    //create database-safe strings
    $m = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['m']);
    $d = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['d']);
    $y = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['y']);
}

//show events for this day
$getEvent_sql = "SELECT event, date_format(startdate, '%l:%i %p') as fmt_date FROM calendar WHERE month(startdate) = '".$m."' AND dayofmonth(startdate) = '".$d."' AND year(startdate) = '".$y."' ORDER BY startdate";
$getEvent_res = mysql_query($getEvent_sql) or die(mysql_error($mysql));

if (mysql_num_rows($getEvent_res) > 0) {
    $event_txt = "<ul>";
    while ($ev = @mysql_fetch_array($getEvent_res)) {
        $event = stripslashes($ev['event']);
        $fmt_date = $ev['fmt_date'];

        $event_txt .= "<li>".$event."</li>";
    }
    $event_txt .= "</ul>";
    mysql_free_result($getEvent_res);
} else {
    $event_txt = "";
}

// close connection to MySQL
mysql_close();

if ($event_txt != "") {
    echo "<p><strong>Courses:</strong></p>
    $event_txt
    <hr/>";
}

// show form for adding an event

    require('../connect.php');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `course`";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

?>

<form method="post" action="event.php">

            <p><label>Select Course: </label>
            <select name="event" id="event" style="position: relative;left: 95px; width: 175px;">
            <?php 
            while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            ?> 
            <option value="<?php echo $line['name'];?>"> <?php echo $line['name'];?> </option>
            <?php }
            ?>
            </select></p>

            <input type="hidden" name="m" value="<?php echo $m; ?>"></input>
            <input type="hidden" name="d" value="<?php echo $d; ?>"></input>
            <input type="hidden" name="y" value="<?php echo $y; ?>"></input>

<button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Add Course</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
<?php
// close connection to MySQL
mysql_close();
?>
```

**calendar.php**

```
<?php
define("ADAY", (60*60*24));
if ((!isset($_POST['month'])) || (!isset($_POST['year']))) {
    $nowArray = getdate();
    $month = $nowArray['mon'];
    $year = $nowArray['year'];
} else {
    $month = $_POST['month'];
    $year = $_POST['year'];
}

$start = mktime (12, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year);
$firstDayArray = getdate($start);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo "Calendar: ".$firstDayArray['month']." ".$firstDayArray['year']; ?></title>
<style type="text/css">
    table {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 6px;
        font-weight: bold;
        background: #ccc;
    }
    td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 6px;
        vertical-align: top;
        width: 100px;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function eventWindow(url) {
    event_popupWin = window.open(url, 'event', 'resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, toolbar=no,width=400,height=150');
    event_popupWin.opener = self;
}
</script>
<body>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<select name="month">
<?php
$months = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May",  "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
for ($x=1; $x <= count($months); $x++) {
    echo"<option value=\"$x\"";
    if ($x == $month) {
        echo " selected";
    }
    echo ">".$months[$x-1]."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<select name="year">
<?php
for ($x=2014; $x<=2024; $x++) {
    echo "<option";
    if ($x == $year) {
        echo " selected";
    }
    echo ">$x</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Go!</button>
</form>
<br/>
<?php
$days = Array("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat");
echo "<table><tr>\n";
foreach ($days as $day) {
    echo "<th>".$day."</th>\n";
}
for ($count=0; $count < (6*7); $count++) {
    $dayArray = getdate($start);
    if (($count % 7) == 0) {
        if ($dayArray['mon'] != $month) {
            break;
        } else {
            echo "</tr><tr>\n";
        }
    }
    if ($count < $firstDayArray['wday'] || $dayArray['mon'] != $month) {
        echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>\n";
    } else {

        require('../connect.php');
         $chkEvent_sql = "SELECT event FROM calendar WHERE
                          month(startdate) = '".$month."' AND
                          dayofmonth(startdate) = '".$dayArray['mday']."'
                          AND year(startdate) = '".$year."' ORDER BY startdate";
         $chkEvent_res = mysql_query($chkEvent_sql)
                         or die(mysql_error($mysql));

         if (mysql_num_rows($chkEvent_res) > 0) {
              while ($ev = mysql_fetch_array($chkEvent_res)) {
                   $event .= stripslashes($ev['event'])."<br/>";
              }
         } else {
              $event = "";
         }

        echo "<td><a href=\"javascript:eventWindow('event.php?m=".$month.
         "&amp;d=".$dayArray['mday']."&amp;y=$year');\">".$dayArray['mday']."</a>
         <br/><br/>".$event."</td>\n";
         $start += ADAY;
    }
}
echo "</tr></table>";

//close connection to MySQL
mysql_close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help will be appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: I laugh at your "create database-safe strings". They're anything but... It's one thing to be aware of sql injection problems and deliberately ignore it. It's another thing entirely to start slapping in comments about how safe you're making things and not actually doing anything at all.

Comment: hey, yea, that bit is not actually my code. thank you for the heads up on that, will definitely fix it up.